# Removing certain files in a series of subdirectories

Tags: command-line, files, find, rm

I have a directory that has several subdirectories in it. Each subdirectory has several files in it. I want to delete all the files in the subdirectories except the .pdf ones. And leave the subdirectories alone. I used

```
find . -type f ! -iname "*.pdf" -delete
```

But I have to be in the subdirectory to make it work.  I want to do it recursively too.

Comment: What OS and version of `find` (`find --version`) do you use?

Comment: add few lines of output without the `-delete` option and tell us which ones you want to delete and which one to keep

Comment: `!` has a special meaning in shells, did you escape it with a backslash?

Comment: I'm confused between "delete all the files in the subdirectories" and "do it recursively too". Do you want to delete files at layer 2, or 2 and beyond?

Comment: @peterh An `!` only has a special meaning in that context in _very few specific shells_.  `bash` and most other `sh` shells don't have an issue with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Can't you just add the path to the top directory instead of using `.` in the `find` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, to delete all of the non-pdf files in all of the subdirectories of the current one:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm */!(*.pdf)
```

The initial `*/` matches every subdirectory, and the [extglob option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) enables the `!( ... )` pattern that says: match all files *except* what's inside the parenthesis; in this case, the pattern to exclude is `*.pdf`. If you may also have files with `.PDF` as an extension, use this instead:

```
rm */!(*.[pP][dD][fF])
```